# How to Get filename from a variable (url) in php?

Tags: php

That is not about getting file name from the url of current page. I have a php file like that.

```
<?php
$fileurl = 'http://example.com/filepath/filepath2/myfile.doc';
?>
```

here, The page's url doesn't matter. I need to extract filename from `$fileurl`. All I need to get myfile.doc from `$fileurl` to
Something like `echo $filename;`

Output: `myfile.doc`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `basename()` function in php to return a file name from the path.Use the code below

```
<?php

    $fileurl = 'http://example.com/filepath/filepath2/myfile.doc';
    $file_name=basename($fileurl);
echo $file_name; // Will output myfile.doc

?>
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $fileurl = 'http://example.com/filepath/filepath2/myfile.doc';
    echo basename($fileurl);

?>
```

Output:

```
myfile.doc
```

Comment: Yes! that's it. love u

Comment: @SahriarSaikat You're welcome :D Happy new year! (in a few hours)

Comment: I would also like to mention `pathinfo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use string functions like strrpos to get the last position of '/' and then use the substr and strlen functions to get the last part of the string.

$fileurl = 'http://example.com/filepath/filepath2/myfile.doc';
    $file_name=substr($fileurl,strrpos($fileurl,'/')+1,strlen($fileurl));

```
echo $file_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively explode:

```
<?php
echo end(explode('/','http://localhost/login/uploads/blog_images/woman4.jpg'));
```

Output:

```
woman4.jpg
```